# How to unwrap previously textured .obj in Blender?

Tags: texturing, uv, import

I have an .obj file that has been previously unwrapped with the coordinates included in the file, however when I select the object and open the UV/Image Editor I am not seeing the UVs. Is it possible there is a step I am missing here? I have tried selecting the object in object mode as well as selecting all vertices of the object in edit mode. I am currently running version 2.74.

The models I am attempting to load are the CS:GO workbench materials located [HERE](http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/resources.html).

Comment: I don't understand the problem exactly. When I open .obj files that have been previously unwrapped in another software, the UVs appear in Blender's UV/Image Editor. Can you elaborate more about the problem?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details about what is happening and have given a link to the files I am attempting to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually turned out to be that I had a previously rendered image open that was displaying over the uv editor. Whenever I closed that image everything showed up as expected.